# Android Contact Birthday Event.START_DATE getlong returns year

Tags: android, android-contacts

Working on contact database:

Long longDate = dataTableCursor.getLong(dataTableCursor          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));

It returned me year "2012" whereas i was expecting the complete date being converted into long value.

Kindly let me know if im going wrong somewhere.

Comment: By long value you mean like in milliseconds?

Comment: Yes i was expecting long milliseconds value whereas it return me 2012

Answer (score 0):

In the Event Content Provider, the START_DATE is a TEXT : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.html#START_DATE

So, to format your date, use :

```
SimpleDateFormat datePattern = new SimpleDateFormat ("yy-MM-dd");
        try {
            Date date = datePattern.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```